# Page disappears after enabling/disabling module or after clearing all caches

Tags: 7, views, routes

I have a page provided by Views (no custom coding). After I enable/disable any module, or after I clear Drupal caches, this page disappears. When I go to this view configuration page, hit any field, hit apply and save the view (without any changes - I just hit apply on field config) - page is coming back. Probably someone deleting view's menu_route? How can I identify who is deleting it?

Comment: What do you means by disappearing the page? Do you see Page Not Found message or a white screen?

Comment: I see page with header & footer, but with no content